# Python readinging from txt file and sending to email not working

Tags: python, file, smtplib

My first time using stackoverflow sorry, if anything is formatted incorrectly

I'm trying to read the file and turn it into a string text and send it to an email, but the email body is always empty. The subject line is there though.

```
with open ("Pokebab Receipt.txt", "w+") as receipt:
    receipt.write("PokeBab Receipt\n")
    for item in customer_order:
        receipt.write(item["Name"])
        receipt.write("\n")
    receipt.write("-------------")
    total = str(customer_total)
    receipt.write(f"Total: {total}")
with open ("Pokebab Receipt.txt", "r") as final:
    receipt_final_send = final.read()
    print("dfsfd")
    print(receipt_final_send)
    print("sdadaaaaaaa")
    connecton.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=customer_email, msg = f"Subject: PokeBab Receipt\n\n "
        f"{receipt_final_send}")
```

[This is the txt File im trying to read from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocmqL.png)

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wazk.png)

[This is the email I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fogqN.png)

Comment: Please fix your formatting and don't post images of text

Answer (score 0):

You use `with open ("Pokebab Receipt.txt", "r") as final:` in a wrong place. That's why you trying to read empty file content. Because when you do `receipt.write("PokeBab Receipt\n")` it is not go to the file, it is going to the application buffer. To send this writing to the file (actually data will go to the kernel buffer cache, [look at this](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync), but that's another matter) we need to call `flush()` or `close()` method. But `close()` method will be called when `with` block ended. So you can call `flush()` method in first `with` block after the `receipt.write(f"Total: {total}")`, or you can open the same file outer of the first `with` block to be able to get most recent file content.

````
with open ("Pokebab Receipt.txt", "w+") as receipt:
    receipt.write("PokeBab Receipt\n")
    for item in customer_order:
        receipt.write(item["Name"])
        receipt.write("\n")
    receipt.write("-------------")
    total = str(customer_total)
    receipt.write(f"Total: {total}")

    receipt.flush()

    with open ("Pokebab Receipt.txt", "r") as final:
        receipt_final_send = final.read()
        print("dfsfd")
        print(receipt_final_send)
        print("sdadaaaaaaa")
        connecton.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=customer_email, msg = f"Subject: PokeBab Receipt\n\n "
                                                                                  f"{receipt_final_send}")```
````

Comment: Thanks it worked! but just to verify, when I read files and write it to a file it doesn't actually go to the file until the file is closed correct? and by using flush we kind of "forcefully" push it into the file without it needing to close?

Comment: My answer is missing, there is one more thing. If you fill up the buffer then python will flush the buffer, so data will go to the file. When will be buffer  fill up ? It depends on the buffer size. On many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long